# How do I constrain a class to implement a particular static method?

Tags: java, parameterized-types

I have the following classes that I'm using in a Kafka application:

```
public abstract class SerdeEnabled< Tse > {
    abstract public Serde< Tse > getSerde();
}

public class SerdeUsing< Tsu extends SerdeEnabled > {
    public void method() {
        Tsu tsu = new Tsu();  // Compile Error: cannot instantiate the type Tsu
        Serde< Tsu > serde = tsu.getSerde();
    }
}
```

As noted this doesn't compile.  Now, the method `getSerde()` does not depend on the
instance data of its respective class, and could in fact be `static` except for the
fact that Java doesn't allow static methods in abstract classes (or interfaces).

I guess I could force this to work by making `SerdeUsing.method` take a Tsu instance,
and then use that to invoke `getSerde`, but this seems ugly.

Any suggestions for how to get the intended effect?

Answer (score 0):

- java 8 allows static method in interface
- you cannot invoke constructor on Tsu because it's a type parameter.

So it's possible to extract the getSerde() method to an  interface as static method and make SerdeEnabled implements this interface.

Comment: Thank you.   However, I'm still stuck because the interface won't let me define a static method `static Serde< Tsu > getSerde(...)`, giving me a similar error because `Tsu` is a type parameter of the interface.  Is there any work-around for this?

Comment: static<Tsu> Serde<Tsu> getSerde() { ..}